# Can't upload to app store due to a missing screenshot

Tags: xcode4.5, app-store-connect

Status of my app is ready to upload

I upload but I forget to add one screenshot.

No problem. Just upload again.

However, the status of my app now is no longer "ready to upload" but missing 1 screenshot.

Hence, when I tried to upload again what I got is:

> Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they
>   can be validated or submitted from within Xcode.

What should I do? I know I was missing one screenshot. I already add that now. So now what? I can't upload that screen shot if I can't upload the app. I can't upload the app because the status is "missing 1 screenshot" rather than ready to upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go back to iTunes Connect and edit the meta data and/or the data of your application to add that one missing screenshot and that should set the status to "Ready to Upload".

Comment: What I did is just reject the binary and start over again.

Comment: yep! That's another way to do it. The portal is not the most straightforward thing to use.

Comment: Actually your answer is more correct. Not simply because the project has screenshot means those screenshot will be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

In iTunes connect, select binary detail.

After that select reject this binary.

Then click ready for upload.

Tada status goes back to the way it used to be.